# Is it possible to use a whip as an instrument because it creates a "sonic boom?" Furthermore, can they attack while "performing?"

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack

I noticed that a whip when used creates a sonic boom.
The definition of a musical instrument is as follows (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_instrument)):

> A musical instrument is a device created or adapted to make musical sounds. In principle, any object that produces sound can be considered a musical instrument—it is through purpose that the object becomes a musical instrument.

Under performance (PHB, page 179) it reads:

> Your Charisma (Performance) check determines how well you can delight an audience with music, dance, acting, storytelling, or some other form of entertainment.

Because of this, I was wondering if I could do something akin to a bladedancer with whips for dancing and use my charisma modifier to attack as my character danced around the battlefield. As far as I know, that's not an option in 5e (at least not with officially available material, but material allowed under *Unearthed Arcana* would work).

If an altered bladedancer is not an option, I was thinking maybe bard/ranger (bard 1st) with war caster feat and dual wielding. Would this work?

Comment: I was thinking bard combined with something else. As I said the idea is to do something similar to the bladedancer, but as far as I know it doesn't exist in 5e. But it would be modified to use whips instead if it did.

Comment: "A whip is a musical instrument because it can make a sonic boom" - by that logic *anything* could be dual-purposed as a musical instrument. A shield makes a sound when bashed with a blunt weapon, so does that mean it's a musical instrument too?

Comment: @Philipp I think my point was because it's a) controllable to a VERY large degree b) part of how the weapon works (it's VERY difficult to use a whip without causing such things) c) thematically appropriate to a dancing character.

Comment: Every weapon that I'm aware of makes a sound when attacking. I still don't see why a whip is special just because it breaks the sound barrier.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson that's because you don't know the [Good Ol' Blues Brothers Boys Band](https://youtu.be/RdR6MN2jKYs?t=48), I guess?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson try breaking the sound barrier with basically any other melee weapon. They're simply not designed to do that! The whip actually IS by what it is. And IIRC there *are* examples of magical whips that amplify this fact

Comment: @JesseCohoon Only a tiny part of a whip does the supersonic travel and only in the very last moment *if* you yank at the whip in the right moment and induce a looping motion, then the tip will travel at 170 meters per second trailing behind the previous segment right before flipping over in the other direction and traveling that speed traveling before the segment, At that moment for a few milliseconds, it travels above 340 meters per second *just* while flipping direction. [It's complicated and works with just a knot at the end...](https://youtu.be/AnaASTBn_K4?list=TLPQMTcwMzIwMjITl1NyPrNr5w)

Comment: See also [this](http://publica.fraunhofer.de/dokumente/PX-30266.html) and [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167278903002215) paper, which were referenced in said demonstration. The moment of shockwave generation can be seen in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/apriljennchoi/status/1079057054399107073). I couldn't find a Paper by Hazeli or Sandlin on the topic yet, but it takes often about 5 years from the experiment to the doctorate paper.

Answer (score 13):

## You can't use a performance check for an attack

[Attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack) in 5e are an entirely separate mechanic from [ability checks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AbilityChecks). The weapons define what ability is scored is used, and are generally are based off of STR or DEX.

However, some classes do allow you to use different ability scores for your attack rolls. Some examples of this are the Warlock (hexblade), which allow you to use Charisma, or spells like *shillelagh* which allow you to use your spellcasting modifier.

Picking one of those options that mechanically allow this will provide you the ability to narrate your attack how you'd like.

### Performance while attacking

The above being said, you can describe how you're attacking however you'd like. And a DM could ask for an ability check of any variety they would like that they think fits your narration. It's unlikely to have any impact on the attack itself, but it will change your how you narrate your attack.

Comment: Can both be done simultaneously, even if it's more rolls?

Comment: @JesseCohoon A DM can ask you for a roll whenever they'd like, but I'm not sure I'd start having someone make two rolls for something that normally requires one. That's what adv/disadvantage generally does and I don't think this applies to that.

Answer (score -1):

### You can use the whip as an instrument, but not with your attack bonus

As [NautArch's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166788/is-it-possible-to-use-a-whip-as-an-instrument-because-it-creates-a-sonic-boom/166789#166789) elaborates, making a performance and attacking are two entirely different things, and use two different rules mechanics. Your attack proficiency with a weapon is about making an attack, as per page 193f, PHB:

> Whether you’re striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or making an attack roll as part of a spell, an attack has a simple structure. 1. Choose a target (...)

You choose a target, apply modifiers make an attack roll, and deal damage (and with some attacks, special effects). This process is what you are proficient with. It has nothing to do with artfully creating sounds to entertain, and therefore you will not be able to use your attack bonus for that purpose.

You could argue that **gladiatorial games**, where you are actually fighting against another creature to entertain the audience, could be seen as a performance. How this would be handled however would be up to your DM, there are no specific rules for it. He might demand a separate Charisma (Performance) check to see if you not only fight effectively but also entertainingly, or he might choose another way to resolve this.

#### Musical performance with a whip

There is real-world precedent for people using all kinds of objects to create sound and entertain, from the [Blue Man Group](https://www.blueman.com/) using tubes, to [people actually using dual wielded whips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QquXdrDcX7I). This is entirely different from attacking, it is using the same object, a whip, in a very different way, as a musical instrument.

With 5e's game mechanics, using the whip in this way would require a Tools Proficiency (page 154, PHB) in Musical Instrument (Whip). It would have nothing to do with your attack proficiency bonus.

> If you have proficiency with a given musical instrument, you can add your proficiency bonus to any ability checks you make to play music with the
> instrument.

That means, if you were making a Charisma (Performance) check to entertain your audience with the whip's sounds, you then would be able to add your proficiency bonus to the check.

#### Approximating a blade dancer in 5e

It appears your main objective is not to entertain an audience using a whip, but to play a "bladedancer" character concept. The game has several options for this

- **The Warlock (Hexblade)** from Xanathar's Guide to Everything. This directly allows you to use your Charisma bonus for weapon attacks with a weaopon of your choice (which could be a whip), although not with a second-hand weapon for dual wielding.
- **The Wizard (Bladesinger)** from Tasha's Cauldron of Everyting, starting at second level. "*Bladesingers master a tradition of wizardry that incorporates swordplay and dance.*" This will give you proficiency with a one-handed melee weapon of choice (which could be a whip), light armor and a Performance skill proficiency, and allow you to enter Bladesong, for an array of melee combat releated benefits.
- **The Rogue (Swashbuckler)** from Xanathar's Guide to Everything, starting at third level. While it does not allow substituting Charisma for Dexterity in attacks, it states "*your method of fighting look s almost like a performance.*", and allows adding your Charisma bonus to initiative, and later on to beguile your opponents with the *Panache* feature.
- **Multiclassing builds**: your suggestion of combining a bard and ranger, with war caster and dual wielding would be able express your character idea, of a dual-wielding character that is able to perform; you would however not be able to apply your Charisma bonus to your weapon attacks. If you just want the performance ability, the *Entertainer* background, combined with any character class that can use whips would work, too.

Comment: There are rules for performance checks in gladiatorial games in an oooold AL module ("Blood & Shackles," maybe?); being season 2 or 3 (IIRC) they're sorta-semi-official, as that was before much of AL-work was devolved to DM's Guild? In any case, just leaving a breadcrumb if you wanted to go digging for mixed metaphors.